# NUnit - Fails with TestFixtureSetUp method not allowed on a SetUpFixture

Tags: c#, nunit

I am trying to re-organise some Integration Tests we have so that they use a common class for creating a Database and the Data required in the Database to Test against in other classes in the same assembly using [SetUpFixture] NUnit attribute.

I have :

```
namespace Tests;

public class TestBaseClass : SolutionBaseClass
{
    public void Setup()
    {
        base.CreateDatabase();
        base.CreateData();
    }

    public void Teardown()
    {
        base.DestroyDatabase();
    }
}

[SetUpFixture]
public class Setup : TestBaseClass
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        base.Setup();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Teardown()
    {
        base.Teardown();
    }
}
```

then individual test fixture classes:

```
namespace Tests.Services;

[TestFixture]
public class LibraryTest : TestBaseClass
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void SetupTests()
    {
        // I know am calling the same Setup twice once from SetUpFixture and TestFixture, 
        // I have handled it so that only one Database/Data gets set up once (for safety mostly!)
        base.SetUp();

        // Other class initialisations.
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong, I figure it is a problem with the inheritance model being used, as you can tell I am inheriting this from someone else!!

Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce a problem with your code.  Is the error run-time or compile-time?  What's the exact text of the error?  What version of NUnit are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.6.2 version and the text is "TestFixtureSetUp method not allowed on a SetUpFixture".  However I have answered my own question by removing the call to the base.Setup() and base.Teardown() in [SetUp] and [TearDown] methods.  I'm instantiating the base class by normal methods instead.

Answer (score 20):

In NUnit 3 one should use OneTimeSetUpAttribute and OneTimeTearDownAttribute on the static methods of the [SetUpFixture] class. Source: http://bartwullems.blogspot.nl/2015/12/upgrading-to-nunit-30-onetimesetup.html

In NUnit 2.0

```
[SetUpFixture]
class TestHost
{
    [SetUp]
    public static void AssemblyInitalize()
    {
      //Global initialization logic here
    }
}
```

In NUnit 3.0

```
[SetUpFixture]
class TestHost
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public static void AssemblyInitalize()
    {
      //Global initialization logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give a code example as this link might not be available in the future.

Answer (score 10):

In `NUnit 3.0` `TestFixtureSetUp` and `TestFixtureTearDown` has been renamed to `OneTimeSetUp` and `OneTimeTearDown`.

Here is the documentation link for above changes:

- [SetUp and TearDown Changes](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/setup-teardown/SetUp-and-TearDown-Changes.html)